# How to filter results in HERE v7 Autosuggest response?

Tags: here-api

I'm wondering if it is possible to filter the category of results returned from the /autosuggest endpoint. For my application I would only like locations (towns, city, etc) to be returned.

The previous version of the API supported this filtering functionality.

As a workaround would I need to filter the results returned to the categories that I want myself?

Comment: Having the same question. For me I would like to use the category filter like in the old places endpoint or even better using the category IDs from the "browse" endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I had sent a support question to Here with a similar question and the response may be helpful for you too.

TLDR: There is a 'types' query param that is not in the documentation with the following valid values `administrativeArea, country, state, county, locality, postalCode, city, district, subdistrict, houseNumber, place, street`

> Adding 'types=city' parameter will bring you only cities in the
> result.
>
> e.g.)
> https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=49.9741,8.44181&q=berlin&types=city
>
> Likewise, if you want to obtain only address results, you can do as
> following:
>
> https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=49.9741,8.44181&q=potzdamerplatz&types=administrativeArea,locality,street,houseNumber
>
> Note that locality includes city, postalCode, district, subdistrict.
>
> Or if you want to also add counties, states, or countries, you can add
> 'county', 'state', or 'country' to the 'types' parameter,
> respectively.
>
> You can designate following type for result filters.
>
> administrativeArea country state county locality postalCode city
> district subdistrict houseNumber place street

Comment: Awesome.. This really works. Thank you very much for the answer. @here-api Would be good to have this important field also in the documentation.